# Redirection of the while combined with the heredoc

Tags: bash

Trying the following - but doesn't work:

```
while read -r cfg val
do
        echo "=$cfg=$val="
done
done < <(sed 's/#.*//;/^ *$/d' << CFGVAL )
cfg1 val1

#some comment
cfg2 #val2
   #cfg3 val3   
CFGVAL
```

e.g. want

- redirect the stdin of the `while` loop from output from `sed`
- and the `sed` should read its input from a `HEREDOC`

wanted output

```
=cf1=val1=
=cfg2==
```

e.g. want

- remove comments `#.*`
- skip empty lines

Help please with the multiple redirection. I know, it is possible to solve with

```
while read -r cfg val
do
   #do tests here
   echo "..."
done <<HEREDOC
...
HEREDOC
```

but looking for the 1st solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your here-doc is part of the process substitution.  That means it needs to be inside the parens.  You need to move the close-parens:

```
while read -r cfg val
do
        echo "=$cfg=$val="
done < <(sed 's/#.*//; /^ *$/d' << CFGVAL
cfg1 val1

#some comment
cfg2 #val2
   #cfg3 val3   
CFGVAL
)
```

This produces the output:

```
=cfg1=val1=
=cfg2==
```